# Creating conditionals based off of a specific view the user is on. (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an admin tool in which I have players. Within the players I have an index page, but I also have a search page. Within the search page I have some search parameters and then render the index table underneath it.  Now each player I have the ability to enable, or disable them.  The problem that I'm facing is that within my controller for my enable/disable methods i'm redirected to my players root path.  This was obviously created before I had added the search functionality.

What I am trying to do with this is keep the routes in the right spot. So if I am in the index and hit disable for one of the players, I would like it to remain within the index page. Likewise if I am on the search page and hit disable/enable, I would like it to redirect back to the search page instead of the index page.

Below is my code. I've really tried working within the redirect routes within the controller, but have run into issues with them not being consistent.

In my controller I have this.

```
def disable
 if @player.disable!
   flash[:notice] = 'Player was successfully disabled.'
 else
   flash[:notice] = 'Failed to disable player.'
 end

 if search_player_path.present?
   redirect_to search__player_path
 else
   redirect_to player_path
 end
end

def enable
 if @player.enable!
   flash[:notice] = 'Player was successfully enabled.'
 else
   flash[:notice] = 'Failed to enable player.'
 end

 if search_players_path.present?
   redirect_to search_players_path
 else
   redirect_to players_path
 end
end
```

My routes file is like this

```
  resources :players do
  match :import, action: :import, as: :import, via: [:get, :post], on: :collection
  member do
    put :enable
    put :disable
    put :unexpire
    put :resend_invite
  end
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Finally in my table which is being rendered through the index page, (thus used again in my search page) This is on the front end. (I know....logic in the front end, please forgive me) I have

```
 %td.td-actions
.row-fluid
  = render partial: "zipadmin/shared/table_actions", locals: {resource: patient, actions: [:read, :update]}
  -if player.disabled?
    = link_to enable_player_path(player), :method=>:put, class: 'btn btn-small btn-success' do
      %i.fa.fa-plus
      Enable
  - else
    = link_to disable_player_path(player), :method=>:put, class: 'btn btn-small btn-warning' do
      %i.fa.fa-minus
      Disable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, simply redirect_to :back

This will take the user back to whatever page they left. I think that's your question but I'm not sure. If not, I'm happy to adjust me response.

Comment: Oh my goodness that is so much easier than I was making it out to be. Thank you so much!